# Is there a conflict with keyword "extern" for a variable which is also defined in the same C file?

Tags: c, file, global-variables, extern

If I define a global variable in file1.c and also declare it using 'extern' in the same file, is that an error, or is it acceptable?

**file1.c:**

```
extern int x;

int x;
```

I will also declare it using 'extern' it in another file, where I will be using it.

**file2.c:**

```
extern int x;
```

Is this correct/acceptable?

Comment: Hi scico. You have received two answers (admittedly one of them mine). Allow me to make sure that you are aware of this concept: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers It does NOT require you to accept an answer (especially not mine). It is very appropriate to wait for a possibly better answer. But sometime tomorrow you might want to explain what more is missing from the existing answers to completely satisfy you. - Or otherwise to accept one. If a better answer arrives later you can always change your choice of accepted answer. Also there is a little goody for yourself. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is more or less exactly how it is meant to be done.
The `extern` does not so much mean "will be defined IN A DIFFERENT FILE THAN THIS", it is more of a "will be defined in one code file, not necessarily this one".
For bonus points, put the declarations (the lines with `extern`) into a header and include it into both code files, the one with the definition, i.e. the line without `extern` and the other one.
Always only have a single one of the definition line in the total of all code files. This way you avoid a redefinition problem and at the same time make sure not to get the declaration inconsistent across multiple code files. (Think of maintenance of your code, which might make necessary to change the definition and declaration of the variable.)
That said, try to avoid global variables as much as possible.

Comment: My confusion is that in file1.c we are defining the variable as well as declaring it as 'extern'.. Are both of these not contradicting to each other? 'extern' means that this variable will be found defined in some other translation-unit (file). But then I also define it in the same file. So will the compiler or linker expect to find this variable from some other file or will they use its definition from the same file file1.c?

Comment: As long as it does not contradict the definition (or other declarations) that is more or less exactly how it is meant to be done. The concept of including headers with declarations (not definitions) is to basically designed for this. (There are techniques to do definition and declaration in a single line in a header and then make sure that the definition is only effective in a single code file, but that is ugly, please allow me not to go there).

Comment: @scico111: Re “'extern' means that this variable will be found defined in some other translation-unit (file)”: No, it does not. It means (in addition to other effects it has) the variable is not defined **here**, in this particular declaration. It is silent with regard to whether a definition appears in this translation unit or another one.

Answer (score 0):

`extern` is a keyword in C programming language which is used to declare a global variable that is a variable without any memory assigned to it. It is used to declare variables and functions in header files. `extern` can be used access variables across `C files`.

you **define** and **initialize** the variable or the **type** (it could be a struct or any other valid c type), **defining** a variable means assigning the variable the required memory, in `c file`, as a `global` (the scope of this variable is the file it self only) and you `expand` or `extend` its scope by extern it in `h file` or to be more accurate you `declare` it in `h file` (**Declaration** of a variable means that the compiler knows that the variable exists but no memory or data has been assigned to it. you can declare it as many time as you wish!) The main rule is that extern should be used in header files only.

for example:

in file1.c

```
int g_my_global = 0;
```

in file1.h

```
extern int g_my_global ;
```

now each header or c file includes your file1.h will be able to access g_my_global

in file2.c

```
#include "file1.h"
....
/*use g_my_global */  
g_my_global  = 10;
```

Comment: My understanding is that if I do 'extern' in file1.c then it means that this variable will be found as defined in some other file later on. But right after declaring it as 'extern' in file1.c I am also defining this variable is the same file. Are these two things not contradicting to each other? My first guess was that it would not work. But maybe I am missing some understanding here.